# Initialize 2d list in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am new to Java and trying to create a 2d list the size of which isn't fixed.I have a class which looks like this:

```
public class q1 {
    List<List<Integer> > L = new ArrayList<List<Integer> >(); 

    public void set(int m,int n){
        //This is the function which would get the size of the 2d list
    }
}
```

I saw the answers but they had to be of fixed sizes, eg:

```
ArrayList<String>[][] list = new ArrayList[10][10];
```

But, I want different sizes of the list **L** for different objects. There were other options like **copyOf**, but can the above functionality be achieved just by this array?

Comment: Please try not to mix up different terms. Vector, ArrayList, and array are all totally different things from each other.

Comment: oh sorry ,removed word "vector" ,didn't know the difference between list and ArrayList.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are mixing two things in your question, `ArrayLists` and `arrays`. `ArrayList` is a variable size container backed by an `array`. `ArrayList` has a [`constructor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-) where you can specify the initial capacity you need so with `ArrayLists` it will look like:

```
public class q1 {
    List<List<Integer>> L; 
    public void set(int m, int n){
        L = new ArrayList<>(m); // assuming m is the number or rows
        for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
            L.add(new ArrayList<>(n)); 
        }
        // now you have a List of m lists where each inner list has n items
    }
}
```

With arrays, the syntax is slightly different:

```
public class q1 {
    Integer[][] L; 
    public void set(int m, int n){
        L = new Integer[m][]; // assuming m is the number or rows
        for(int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
            L[i] = new Integer[n]; 
        }
        // now you have a array of m arrays where each inner array has n items
    }
}
```

Moreover if all the inner arrays will have the same length `(n)` the `set` method could be simplified to:

```
    public void set(int m, int n){
        L = new Integer[m][n]; // assuming m is the number or rows
        // now you have a array of m arrays where each inner array has n items
    }
```

Comment: @Saurabh you bet! Glad I could help.

Comment: `L = new Integer[m][n];` would do the same thing with much less code.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException yes you are absolutely correct. I had my mind fixed on lists and didn't think of that case. I've updated my answer to include that case. Good catch! Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @Saurabh i've updated my answer to include another way to initialize the arrays.

Comment: @StaticBeagle,thanks for an updated answer and I don't know why my first comment regarding a thanking note on your answer is not showing, didn't delete it.

Comment: @Saurabh no worries.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such special syntax for `List`s, but you could always just iterate over the number of smaller lists and initialize them individually. Note that passing the size to the `ArrayList`'s constructor doesn't really set its size, but it is does allocate the space, and may save you rellocations in the future:

```
public void set(int m,int n){
    l = new ArrayList<>(m);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        l.add(new ArrayList<>(n));
    }
}
```